# jquery custom method question,

Tags: jquery, validation

I added a captcha to my form and I want to validate this field.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("matchCaptcha", function(value,element)  {
    return  this.optional(element) || value == '#request.strCaptcha#';
});
```

`#request.strCaptcha#` this part simply returns an alphanumeric char something like 'cZk9ljW'

under the rules, i added:

```
captcha : { matchCaptcha : true }
```

The validation does not run and I get no errors from script. What am I doing wrong? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Everything you posted sounds fine, which probably means it's something you haven't posted.

1. You're doing your `addMethod` inside a `$(document).ready()`, right?
2. Have you run this with a debug `alert()` inside the validation function to verify whether it is actually not running, as opposed to running and always returning true?
3. The input name for the captcha's text area is `captcha`, yeah?

If you do add an `alert()` and find the validation method is being called, my recommendation for you is to just get rid of the `this.optional(element) ||` part.  I don't imagine you ever want your captcha to be optional anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This one was tricky a little bit. I am using ColdFusion. I created a custom tag to create and display the captcha. I removed the jQuery.validator.addMethod to after my custom tag call. then I got rid of this.optional(element) || part. Also, had to add another $().ready(function() { ... });

So, it looks like:

$().ready(function() {
jQuery.validator.addMethod("matchCaptcha", function(value,element)  {
    return value == '#request.strCaptcha#';
    });
});

I still have captcha : { matchCaptcha : true } over in the validation rules. Thanks for the heads up.